# sending email is not working with my smtp server

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following is my coding for sending email with my smtp server. but it throws an smtpexception as failure to sent .

I am using windows webserver for my website.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
        // Sender e-mail address.
        Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text);
        // Recipient e-mail address.
        Msg.To.Add("info@dhuvara.com");
        Msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        Msg.Body = txtMessage.Text;
        Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        // your remote SMTP server IP.
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "mail.dhuvara.com"; 
        smtp.Port = 25;
        Msg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@dhuvara.com", "SolaiMail");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(Msg);
        //Msg = null;
        lbltxt.Text = "Thanks for Contact us";
        // Clear the textbox valuess
        txtName.Text = "";
        txtSubject.Text = "";
        txtMessage.Text = "";
        txtEmail.Text = "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Exceptions contain more than the class name.  What was the *message*?

Comment: Can you paste the exception message?

Comment: "Failure sending mail." this is the exception message from my code.

Comment: Are you sure the user account you are providing has access to send email out via SMTP?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

It needs to be before you set the credentials.

Comment: Let's see the whole exception.  Instead of using ex in your message, please use ex.ToString().  That will dump the stack and all of the details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set EnableSSL = false;

It might be the problem - i've run into this problem before.

Comment: I tried this is also.but still the same error occur. please look my code.

Comment: Post the values of your textboxes. Replace all txt's with the values of them.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that mail.dhuvara.com is the right host to connect to.
DNS lookup for this host tells me, that it is a CNAME for go.domains.live.com and go.domains.live.com is a CNAME for domains.live.com, so I assume that you are using windows live to host your domain. Maybe you should try smtp.live.com as the mail server instead.